# How to get each pattern from regex

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
var patterns = new string[] { @"Regex 1 Pattern", @"Regex 2 Pattern", @"Regex 3 Pattern" }; 

var rx = new Regex(string.Join("|", patterns), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

In the above code how to get **rx** value to display.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx), you can call `toString` on a `Regex` object and it will:

> Returns the regular expression pattern that was passed into the Regex constructor.

Which in this case is your concatenated string!

```
rx.toString()
```

Alternatively, why don't you put the string into a variable first, then pass it into the regex constructor:

```
var regexString = string.Join("|", patterns);
Console.WriteLine(regexString); // Here you can print the regex out now!
var rx = new Regex(regexString, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

If you want to get the patterns one by one, simply use a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach(var pattern in patterns) {
    Console.WriteLine(pattern);
}
```

Comment: rx contains 3 values.. need to get one by one what is the code for that

Comment: @rajeshgonugunta don't you have the `patterns` array already? Loop through it! See the edit.

Comment: @rajeshgonugunta If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!